# Set picture above its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a website footer and a picture of houses.
so my goal is to set the picture of houses above foooter.
Now my structure looks likes this:

```
<div class="footer">
     <img class="homes" src="img/homes.png" > 
</div>
```

So what should write in my css file to setthe picture of houses upper than my footer

```
.footer {
        background: rgb(59, 59, 59);
    }


.homes {
}
```

[image: footer and picture]

Comment: a negative `margin-top`?

Comment: here what part of it is actually image and what part footer

Comment: @user3127499 Hello. You should use a sticky footer and add your houses insides. They are elements of the footer. Now, use a negative `margin-top` to push them outsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click  here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jM5p2/)

### CSs

```
.footer {
    background: rgb(59, 59, 59);
    margin-top:30px;   
}

.homes {
    margin-top:-30px;       
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <img class="homes" src="http://placehold.it/250x100" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sticky footer and add your houses inside. They are elements of the footer. Now, use a negative `margin-top` to push them outsite.

```
.footer .home {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100px; // here we go
    margin-left: 42px;
}
```

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/4nu4p/2/)**